# How to deal with links with poor or bad WOT rating?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I've just stumbled upon [this answer at SU](https://superuser.com/questions/162916/convert-my-jpeg-files-with-best-quality/163013#163013) which links against a site with very poor reputation at [WOT](http://www.mywot.com/) (including warnings for viruses, phishing and the like).

Should we replace those links, should we remove them or let them be?

Comment: In doubt, always flag for moderator, I love checking the flags (this first week, at least).

Comment: @Popular Demand: Oh yeah, sorry, Web of Trust...added link.

Comment: Grazie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a comment informing the OP. Encourage them to change the link themselves to something similar, but without the warnings (if possible). Temporarily edit out the link (if it is extraneous), or modified it as outlined below if it is critical to the post. Make sure you leave a comment that tells them what you modified.
   If it a new user, you might want to tell them how to edit their posts as well.
2. My personal (completely unsanctioned) solution would be editing

   > **http://possibly-dangerous-link.com/**
   >   to
   >   (*ED:* I received a spoofing alert from the following link.) http:_//possibly-dangerous-link.com/
3. If the link if formatted

   > "an example found [here](http://possibly-dangerous-link.com/)"
   >   to
   >   "an example found at the following link: (*ED:* I received a spoofing alert from the following link.) http:_//possibly-dangerous-link.com/"

Replace "spoofing" with whatever warning you received.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "Make sure you give them ample time to do this", as a link to a spam, malware, or spyware site is a serious broken window, and just bad business.  I don't want people saying "I went to SuperUser.com and got a virus".  I like your solution though.

Comment: @C. Ross: good point. edited.

Comment: edited the given example with something similar to your suggestion. I left the link available only to editors, it's not visible to the rest of users, and replaced by a notification like yours. Didn't leave a comment, since the "revision" in itself should be enough to notify.

Comment: @Gnoupi, only if the poster knows how to edit and view revision history. But I agree, that link was sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

If this DB is programmatically acceptable, then should the Stack Exchange engine automatically query it for all URLs submitted, and add an appropriate warning for suspect links?

Comment: There is a [WOT API](http://www.mywot.com/wiki/API) that allows you to programmatically obtain the "reputation" of a given site. T&Cs apply to it which may not be ideal for SO. This answer might be better off posted as a separate feature request.

Comment: I agree with Andy. That would make a pretty interesting feature request...especially since most spammers would be also caught with it.